# Unable to switch to new window with Black URL in selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am unable to switch to the window which is having blank URL. Actually I am opening a popup with `window.open("","MsgWindow")`. I am getting the Handle name using `driver.WindowHandles`. However, while trying switch to this window it is throwing TimeOut Exception. I tried with the lasted version of ChromeDriver(2.31)

Comment: Which `Selenium` binding? `Selenium` version?

Comment: Selenium Version 3.4. I found the similar bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=450 Is there any workaround? I am using Selenium for C#.

Comment: I don't feel there should be any issue. Can you consider updating your code block along with the manual steps which you are trying to Automate? Thanks